# display text and textfield in signle line

Tags: html, css

we are using below code to display text and textfield as like below :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTL1K.png

```
<li class="inline-label">
<label for="summary_field" class="required"><em></em><?php echo $this->__('Review Title :') ?></label>
<div class="input-box">

<input type="text" name="title" id="summary_field" class="input-text required-entry" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($data->getTitle()) ?>" />
</div>
<p>( Maximum 60 characters )</p>
</li>
```

but i wanted to display both text & textfield in single line as below :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdAEO.png

Comment: This can be done by CSS please show us what your CSS looks like so we can see what might be wrong with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.input-box {
  width:100%;
}
.inline-label {
  display: inline-block;
  width:100%;
}
.required {
  float: left;
  padding-right: 15px;
}
p {
   float:left;
   margin-top:5px;
}
.input-box {
    width: 70%;
    float: left;
}
.input-text {
   width:100%;
   
}
```

```html
<li class="inline-label">
   <label for="summary_field" class="required">
     <em>Review Title</em>
  </label>
   <div class="input-box">
       <input type="text" name="title" id="summary_field" class="input-text required-entry" value="">
  <p style="
    float: left;
">( Maximum 60 characters )</p>
   </div>
   
</li>
```

Comment: thnaks for support.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
.inline-label>.input-box
{
  display:inline-block;
}
```

[Working example](https://codepen.io/apmeena/pen/rLzajo)

Comment: thnaks for support.